# Transfering a row data from one table to another in jquery datatable shows [object Object]

Tags: jquery, web-services, datatables, asp.net-ajax

i use image mapster for mapping human image.when i click a part of it organ name send as parameter to web service.Code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public void GetSymptoms(String organ_name)
    {
        List<symps> listSymptoms = new List<symps>();

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EhealtsCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sendSymptoms", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = "@organ";
            parameter.Value = organ_name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                symps symp = new symps();
                symp.Sympt = rdr["SymptomsName"].ToString();
                listSymptoms.Add(symp);

            }

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listSymptoms));
        }
```

It returns symptoms name as json data for specific organ which i bind using datatable.now i want to transfer row value of this table to another table.
Code:

```
$('#manLeg').mapster($.extend({}, options,{

    onClick: function (e) {

        if (e.key === 'toes')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "SympsService.asmx/GetSymptoms",
                data: { organ_name: "toes" },
                method: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#symptomsTable').DataTable({
                        destroy: true, paging: false, searching: false, info: false, data: data,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                'data': 'Sympt',
                                'title': 'Shin Symptoms',
                                class: 'center'
                            },
                        {
                            "targets": [-1],
                            'data': null,
                            render: function () {
                                return "<button type='button'>Choise</button>"
                            }
                        }
                        ]

                    });
                    $("#symptomsTable button").on("click", function (evt) {

                        var table1 = $("#symptomsTable").DataTable();
                        var table2 = $("#choiseTable").DataTable();
                        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
                        var row = table1.row(tr);
                        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row.data()));
                        row.remove().draw();
                        table2.row.add(data).draw();
                    });

                    $("#choiseTable").DataTable({
                        destroy: true, paging: false, searching: false, info: false,
                        columns: [
                           {
                               data:null,
                               'title': 'Selected Symptoms'
                           }
                        ]
                    });

                },
```

when i clicked choice button a row is removed and new row created in second table but the value can not pass. in new row it show [object Object] for every row.
PLEASE,can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code.any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: right off the bat, I would replace your built in serializer with Newtonsoft. Its free and it handles dates more intuitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a button click to "move" the row, but this will get the point across.
I created a jsFiddle that uses a row button to move a single row. It also uses a table button to move multiple select rows
https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/sc0bo122/6/

```
        $("#example button").on("click", function (evt) {

            var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var row = table1.row(tr);

            // instead of getting the row, I get the row data.
            // the json stuff is done just to make a copy of the data
            // to ensure it is disconnected from the source.
            var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row.data()));

            // this actually destroys the row so you can't add it to the other table.
            row.remove().draw();

            // then add and draw.
            table2.row.add(data).draw();

        })
```

Comment: can i put button in every row? because i want to every row data transfer to another table row after click that specific row and also delete that row @Bindrid

Comment: @Bindred Thank u so much for ur kindness.there is a problem, when i click button it remove row but in new table it shows [object Object]. i put my new code(using ur code).

Comment: Not surprised.  Off the top of my head, my guess is that the data structure might be different than yours. Can up update your code above to include your data structure and I will take a look on my local environment

Comment: If you know how to use jsFiddle, set it up there.

Comment: i also understand my data structure is different but as i am new i can not figure it out.i include my web service code.is it helping to find my error?? @Bindrid

Comment: It appears that I work in an environment similar to your (c# backend) so I can take a look at it tonight

Comment: @Bindrid Why can't I see entered input value in the second table? In case the user enters a number or name. The input won't show in the second table after user click add button. Or this does not support entering text if one would use input on the first table and be able to see what was entered on the second table when add button is clicked.

Comment: @Bindrid Why can't I see entered input value in the second table? In case the user enters a number or name. The input won't show in the second table after user click add button. Or this does not support entering text if one would use input on the first table and be able to see what was entered on the second table when add button is clicked. Using the very same code on fiddle I have just input to put `salary` as `input`. https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/sc0bo122/6/

Comment: @King , I have a fully editable table (using buttons) example at http://jsbin.com/yafuvah/350/edit?html,css,js,output   is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Bindrid Let me check it and if it's what I want I will be happy.

Comment: @Bindrid I have checked it the example is not what I'm looking for. I want something like the image below that shows two tables moving the record from one table to another. I have found the example but it not working accordingly https://codepen.io/JayStar/pen/ZJpMxG the entered value is empty after clicking the add button.

Comment: @King so you want something closer to this https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/u0vxnp8L/   Click on the amount cell to edit it. When you click off the cell, it updates the data object associated with the cell so the info does not get lost if you move it back to the other table.

Comment: @Bindrid I want some closer to that on the on your jsfiddle. The only thing will be where by user enters a value and have a add button to move the selected items to the second table.

Answer (score 0):

This is my web services class I used to simulate accessing the database.  With a web method you can have a normal return. You don't have to set up the writer, etc.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    namespace WebApplication1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for wsSymptoms
        /// </summary>
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
         [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class SympsService : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            [Serializable]
            public class symps
            {
               public String Sympt { get; set; }
               public symps (String newval) { Sympt = newval; }
               public symps() { }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// This method explicitly serialized the data
            /// which means it has to be json parsed on the client.
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="organ_name"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            [WebMethod(enableSession:false)]
            public string GetSymptomsSerialized(String organ_name )
            {
                // I prefer Newton serializer over microsoft one. The ms on adds more overhead and 
                // causes issue particularly if an object is making a round trip to the client.
                List<symps> list = fakedData();
                String serializedList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
                return serializedList;
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// This method lets the framework take care of the serialization.
            /// This works but its not my personal prefered method
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="organ_name"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            [WebMethod(enableSession:false)]
            public List<symps> GetSymptomsObject(String organ_name)
            {
                return fakedData();
            }
            // since i am not hooked up to a database, just made stuff up.
            private List<symps> fakedData()
            {
                List<symps> list = new List<symps>();
                list.Add(new symps("discolor"));
                list.Add(new symps("pimples"));
                list.Add(new symps("sorness"));
                list.Add(new symps("pain"));
                list.Add(new symps("break"));
                list.Add(new symps("twig"));
                list.Add(new symps("red"));
                list.Add(new symps("green"));
                list.Add(new symps("discolor"));

                return list;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please sir can you look at this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050933/jquery-datatable-ajax-returns-an-error)

Answer (score 0):

[image]I am not sure why you used the "extend" on this stuff.  In the code below, I get  little carried away in that most stuff is in functions and you can move rows in either direction.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            // startup and initialize empty tables for appearance
            $(function ($) {
                createDataTable('#targetTable', null);
                createDataTable("#sourceTable", null);
                // set up event handlers for both directrions
                $('#targetTable').on("click", "tbody button", function (evt) { moveRow(evt, '#targetTable', '#sourceTable'); })
                $('#sourceTable').on("click", "tbody button", function (evt) { moveRow(evt, '#sourceTable', '#targetTable'); })
                $("#divButtons button").on("click", function (evt) {
                    createDataTable('#targetTable', []);
                    runajax('toes', $(evt.target).text())
                })
            })


            // run ajax organ is hard coded to 'toes" above.
            // I have two slightly diffrent web methods that the
            // end result is the same. webmthod parameter just chooses which one
            function runajax(organ, webMethod) {

                $.ajax({

                    url: "SympsService.asmx/" + webMethod,
                    data: { organ_name: organ },
                    method: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ organ_name: "toes" }),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        // for some reason, when WebMethod returns and object its actually in a child of data called d so it needs to be pulled ouit
                        // when I explicitly serialize on the server, have to deserialize here.

                        // the diffrence of webmthod is explained in the web methods
                        var sympList = webMethod == 'GetSymptomsSerialized' ? JSON.parse(data.d) : data.d;
                        createDataTable('#sourceTable', sympList)

                    },
                    error: function (response, status) {
                        console.log(response);
                        debugger;
                    }

                });
            }


            // create data tables.
            function createDataTable(target, data) {

                $(target).DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    paging: false, searching: false, info: false, data: data,
                    columnDefs: [{
                        targets: [-1], render: function () {
                            return "<button type='button'>" + (target == '#targetTable' ? 'Remove' : 'Choose') + "</button>"
                        }
                    }],
                    columns: [
                        {
                            'data': 'Sympt',
                            'title': 'Shin Symptoms',
                            class: 'center'
                        },
                    {
                        'data': null, 'title': 'Action'

                    }
                    ]

                });
            }


            // function to move rows
            function moveRow(evt, fromTable, toTable) {

                var table1 = $(fromTable).DataTable();
                var table2 = $(toTable).DataTable();
                var tr = $(evt.target).closest("tr");
                var row = table1.rows(tr);
                // since we are only dealing with data for once cell I just grab it and make a new data object

                var obj = { 'Sympt': row.data()[0].Sympt };
                table2.row.add(obj).draw();
                row.remove().draw();

            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .flexed table {
                width: 300px;
            }

            .flexed {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Pick Load method:</p>
        <div id="divButtons">
            <button type="Button">GetSymptomsSerialized</button>
            <button type="Button">GetSymptomsObject</button>
        </div>
        <br />&nbsp;
        <div class="flexed">
            <div>
                <table id="sourceTable">
                    <thead><tr><th>Symptom List</th><th>Choose</th></thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table id="targetTable">
                    <thead><tr><th>Symptom List</th><th>remove</th></thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly...Salute to u sir....i cant thank u in single word ..i wish one day i will meet u.... @Bindrid

Comment: My pleasure.  My current assignment has me working with this stuff a lot.