# jquery datatable ajax returns an error

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

here is my code which return symptoms list from web service perfectly in my machine in visual studio 12.

```
$('#manLeg').mapster($.extend({}, options,{

    onClick: function (e) {

        if (e.key === 'toes')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "SympsService.asmx/GetSymptoms",
                method: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ organ_name: "toes" }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    createDataTable('#choiseTable', null);
                    createDataTable("#symptomsTable", null);
                    $('#choiseTable').on("click", "tbody button",  function (evt) { moveRow(evt, '#choiseTable', '#symptomsTable'); } )
                    $('#symptomsTable').on("click", "tbody button", function (evt) { moveRow(evt, '#symptomsTable', '#choiseTable'); })
                    var sympList = 'GetSymptoms' ? JSON.parse(data.d) : data.d;
                    createDataTable('#symptomsTable', sympList);


                    function createDataTable(target, data) {

                        $(target).DataTable({
                            destroy: true,
                            paging: false, searching: false, info: false, data: data,

                            columnDefs: [{

                                targets: [-1], render: function () {
                                    return "<button type='button'>" + (target == '#choiseTable' ? 'Remove' : 'Choose') + "</button>"
                                }
                            }],
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    'data': 'Sympt',
                                    'title': 'toes Symptoms',
                                    class: 'center'
                                },
                            {
                                'data': null, 'title': 'Action'

                            }
                            ]

                        });
                    }


                    function moveRow(evt, fromTable, toTable) {

                        var table1 = $(fromTable).DataTable();
                        var table2 = $(toTable).DataTable();
                        var tr = $(evt.target).closest("tr");
                        var row = table1.rows(tr);

                        var obj = { 'Sympt': row.data()[0].Sympt };
                        table2.row.add(obj).draw();
                        row.remove().draw();

                    }
                },
                error: function (error, status) {
                    console.log(error);
                    debugger;
                }
            });
```

but when i run it in another machine on visual studio 13 it returns error on console.log(error). the error is:

```
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/x.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/x.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/x.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/x.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/x.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/x.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }
```

this drive me crazy because i need to run it on that machine but can not understand what is this error meaning.
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The error handler has **three** parameters. Use all of them.

Comment: This line      var sympList = 'GetSymptoms' ? JSON.parse(data.d) : data.d; makes no sense to me.   If your web service returns a string, you need to JSON.parse. If it returns and object, it will probably be serialized already.  In any case, its behavior will be consistent.

Comment: If you are stopping the debugger line in your visual studio, you should be able to examine the error object.  Check the value in error.responseText or error.response.JSON.message to get the actual error.

Comment: Just as a safety check, change error: function (error, status) to error: function (reqError, status) or anything else but "error" and see if it shows up the same in console.

Comment: Why are your function defined inside your ajax call?

Comment: If that is the whole js section, your { and ( are not balanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reorganized it a bit and come up with this

```
    $('#manLeg').mapster($.extend({}, options,
        {
            onClick: function (e) {
                if (e.key === 'toes') {
                    doAjax();
                }
            }
        }));

    function doAjax() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "SympsService.asmx/GetSymptoms",
            method: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ organ_name: "toes" }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                createDataTable('#choiseTable', null);
                createDataTable("#symptomsTable", null);
                $('#choiseTable').on("click", "tbody button",  function (evt) { moveRow(evt, '#choiseTable', '#symptomsTable'); } )
                $('#symptomsTable').on("click", "tbody button", function (evt) { moveRow(evt, '#symptomsTable', '#choiseTable'); })
                var sympList = 'GetSymptoms' ? JSON.parse(data.d) : data.d;
                createDataTable('#symptomsTable', sympList);
            },
            error: function (responseError, status) {
                console.log(responseError);
                debugger;
            }
        });

    }

    function createDataTable(target, data) {

        $(target).DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            paging: false, searching: false, info: false, data: data,
            columnDefs: [{

                targets: [-1], render: function () {
                    return "<button type='button'>" + (target == '#choiseTable' ? 'Remove' : 'Choose') + "</button>"
                }
            }],
            columns: [
                {
                    'data': 'Sympt',
                    'title': 'toes Symptoms',
                    class: 'center'
                },
            {
                'data': null, 'title': 'Action'

            }
            ]

        });
    }


    function moveRow(evt, fromTable, toTable) {

        var table1 = $(fromTable).DataTable();
        var table2 = $(toTable).DataTable();
        var tr = $(evt.target).closest("tr");
        var row = table1.rows(tr);

        var obj = { 'Sympt': row.data()[0].Sympt };
        table2.row.add(obj).draw();
        row.remove().draw();

    }
```

Comment: I am so sorry for my late comment. Thank you so much for your help.well i tried it another machine and that runs perfectly...so may be that is the problem of visual studio installation. thanks